# SASS append margin to body only if child class exists

Tags: css, sass

I have the following - now I only want the body applied if the element has the sticky class - only now because of the @at-root the body margin is always active - but I need that also to make it work in situ of this nesting.

```
// Sticky
// @todo The body margin is always present even if not sticky
//------------------------------------------------------------------------//
&--sticky {

    @at-root  {

        body {
            margin-bottom : 260px;
        }

        footer#{ & } {
            position         : absolute;
            bottom           : 0;
            width            : 100%;
            height           : 260px;
            background-color : #f5f5f5;
        }

    }

}
```

HTML
    With the above CSS the body margin is applied always - it should not be

```
<footer> 
   blah
<footer>
```

option is

```
With the above CSS the body margin is applied and the footer postion

<footer class="footer--sticky"> 
   blah
<footer>
```

I wanted a work around that if the sticky class is not present then non of the nested css would run

any help appreciated

Comment: What CSS-Code do you expect? How does your HTML look like?

Comment: Updated a little - does this help - lol someone already down voted this without a comment - bit harsh :)

Answer (score 0):

## Try to solve your problem without SASS.

Sass compiles to plain CSS. It can't do anything CSS can't.
If you're not able to solve your problem in css, it is maybe not soveable.

## Accessing Parents

You're trying to do things with & to get to the parent.
I think this is not how it works.
You're seeking for the parent selector (https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) which does not exist in CSS.

## Solution

Possible solution is to give the CSS-Class to the `body`. E.g. `<body class="sticky-footer-is-active">`

I'ts easy to solve your problem now ;-)

You already need Javascript to add/remove the classes from the footer. So you can use it.

## Future

http://html5please.com/#sticky

Comment: Thanks yeah it was a stab in the dark really to see if SASS CSS had pushed onto another level without me reading up on it.